# Cannot install Lazarus IDE on Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: apt, lazarus

I have downloaded *.deb files from Lazarus homepage and used

```
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

in Lazarus folder. It did install, but couldn't run due to error saying:

```
No Lazarus executable in usr/lib/lazarus/0.9.30.2/lazarus
```

So I removed it, and tried to install Lazarus from software manager and with

```
sudo apt-get install lazarus
```

Both with no success. I get following error (translating to english):

```
lazarus: requires: lazarus-ide (>=0.9.28.2-8ubuntu1)
E: Packages are damaged
```

What should I do?

Thanks in advance,
Regards

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround for the first problem:

```
No Lazarus executable in usr/lib/lazarus/0.9.30.2/lazarus
```

Install Lazarus from website (sourceforge.net download site), I also installed fpc.

Go to

```
usr/lib/lazarus/0.30.2
```

and run file

```
lazarus-gtk2
```

instead of

```
startlazarus.
```

IDE runs without problem.

PS.: sysinfo - Ubuntu Lucid 10.04 x64

EDIT:

However after that, apt-get stopped working due to unresolved dependencies. So really I had to remove this version of Lazarus. 
I had huge issues with installing Lazarus from USC, finally aptitude instead of apt-get managed to install it, but it worked improperly. Due to some error I lost my ethernet connection. After restoring my ethernet connection I uninstalled Lazarus using aptitude and installed it from USC and now it works fine :]